# Asynctask cant display the server response

Tags: android, sockets, android-studio, android-asynctask, tcpclient

I created a socket program on android studio and I want to display the response of the server. The problem is when I'm using  textResponse.setText(serverm); it didn't work. this is my code on asynctask

```
private class Connect extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    final String address = editTextAddress.getText().toString();


    String textResponse = null;
    String serverm = null;
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        mRun = true;

            try {
                client = new Socket(address, 3818);
                mBufferIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));


                while (mRun) {
                    serverm = mBufferIn.readLine();

                    if (serverm != null) {
                        System.out.println(serverm);
                        textResponse.setText(serverm);


                    }
                }
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## What's (Likely) Wrong

It looks like you are trying to continuously poll a server and update a text field. An AsyncTask is probably not the best choice of tools to achieve this. The typical use case for AsyncTasks is that you have a single piece of work that will take a long time, and you want to update the UI when it's done.

The (probable) reason your code isn't working is because the AsyncTask's doInBackground method is being run on a background thread but you are trying to update the UI `textResponse.setText(serverm)`. On Android, all updates to UI elements have to happen on the "main" or "UI" thread. Your code is likely throwing an exception on this line and killing the AsyncTask.

## Suggestion

I think a simple background thread along with posting to the UI thread when you have updates would be a more natural fit. With this scheme you have a long living thread that you can perform your networking on that will schedule work to be done on the UI thread when updates need to happen to the UI.

```
// Create an android.os.Handler that you can use to post Runnables 
// to the UI thread.
private static final Handler UI_HANDLER = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

// Create a Runnable that will poll a server and send updates to the
// UI thread.
private final Thread mConnectAndPoll = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        mRun = true;
        try {
            String address = editTextAddress.getText().toString();
            client = new Socket(address, 3818);
            mBufferIn = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));

            while (mRun) {
                serverm = mBufferIn.readLine();

                if (serverm != null) {
                    System.out.println(serverm);
                    // Create a Runnable that will update the 
                    // textResponse TextView with the response from
                    // the server, and schedule it to run on the UI 
                    // thread.
                    UI_HANDLER.post(new UpdateResponseRunnable(serverm));
                }
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});

// Create a subclass of Runnable that will update textResponse.
private class UpdateResponseRunnable implements Runnable {
    private final String mValue;

    public UpdateResponseRunnable(String value) {
        mValue = value;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        textResponse.setText(mValue);
    }
};

// Start the background thread in onCreate or wherever you are
// currently starting your AsyncTask.
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);

    mConnectAndPoll.start();
}
```

Comment: i use this code but it wont work,,,,,,there is a problem on creating the subclass.

Comment: Runnable has no interface expected and UpdateTextResponse is invalid method declaration. i think its just a minor problem but i can't fix it.

Comment: Updated the example code. You should be able to fix those errors by:
 (1) changing `private class UpdateResponseRunnable extends Runnable` to `private class UpdateResponseRunnable implements Runnable` and (2) changing `public UpdateTextResponse` to `public UpdateResponseRunnable`.

Comment: no error now but when I apply it to my android device, the app crash. I don't know if its because my android version is gingerbread. I try to emulate it  too on bluestacks but i get the same result.

Comment: anything interesting in `adb logcat`?

Comment: i add the logcat at the top. I create a subclass like the example code but  I use Asynctask and it works! but I'm curious if I can start my program using  the sample code.can you fix it?

Comment: It looks like it is crashing in the constructor, what is on line 154?

Comment: here it is." final String address = editTextAddress.getText().toString();" . I insert it on the runnable so the address will save on the socket.

Comment: Ah ok, the problem is that you are access the contents of editTextAddress at the initialization of the Thead/AsyncTask. This happens before onCreate is called when you are probably assigning a value to editTextAddress. You can fix the NPE by moving this to the body of the Thread/AsyncTask. I updated to the sample code with this change.

Comment: Thanks for the help! and sorry for the late response. It is working when my code is on the Main class now  I create a new class and I put my codes in there. now there is an error on the part of the subclass. on the textResponse.setText(mValue); the error said "cannot resolve method 'setText(java.lang.string)'. can you teach me how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be accessing Activity level instance variables from your AsyncTask. This can and will lead to memory leaks.

If you want a long-running background task look into Services - then use a `LocalBroadcastReceiver` to propagate data back to your Activity / interested-parties. Or you could use an event bus like Otto or GreenRobot